# How to use async on_message function with python web socket-client library?

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket

When using the websocket-client library, in python, is it possible for the on_message function to be a coroutine ?

I have the following code below:

```
async def on_message(ws, message):
    await get_balance() # runs an aiohttp get request
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(data_feed,on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

This gives me the error

```
 RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'on_message' was never awaited
  callback(self, *args)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `websocket-client` is kinda outdated. You would want to update [python-binance](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance) library version to at least above 1.0.12 and use the `AsyncClient` built in the library to do the asynchronous stuff.

```
from binance import AsyncClient, BinanceSocketManager

async def on_message(res):
   # strategy

async def kline_listener(client):
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    async with bm.kline_socket(symbol='ETHBTC') as stream:
        while True:
            res = await stream.recv()
            print(res)
            # do as you'd do in on_message() or just call on_message()
            await on_message(res)

async def main():
    client = await AsyncClient.create(api_key, secret, tld)
    await kline_listener(client)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

---

*Reference:*

- https://sammchardy.github.io/async-binance-basics/